# Database Design: dating-site-like application?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, normalization

Assume a dating-site-like web application wherein each profile can have one or more users. Each user, say, has the following columns: name, age, gender.

I think the DB design would be something like the following:

```
TABLE profile
=============================
| profile_id | name         |
=============================
| 1          | Dynamic Duo  |
-----------------------------

TABLE user
================================================
| user_id | profile_id | name   | age | gender |
================================================
| 1       | 1          | Batman | 35  | Male   |
------------------------------------------------
| 2       | 1          | Robin  | 25  | Male   |
------------------------------------------------
```

**Is the DB design good?** How would I query for the following:

- Find all profiles where user's gender=Male
- Find all profiles where user's genders are Male and Female
- Find all profiles where user's genders are Male and Female AND each user's age is > 20 and < 40
- Find all profiles where there are more than 2 associated users

If the DB design can't support such queries, what design would?

Comment: Those "How would I query" questions are pretty basic. It looks to me like you might already be in over your head. (That's an observation, not a criticism.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave the gender attribute the type of bit.

The first one would be;

```
-- All male
SELECT * FROM profiles p
  WHERE p.id NOT IN
    (SELECT u.profile_id FROM users u WHERE u.gender != 1);
```

Second;

```
-- Male and female
SELECT * FROM profiles p
  WHERE p.id IN
    (SELECT u.profile_id FROM users u WHERE u.gender = 1)
    AND p.Id IN
    (SELECT u.profile_id FROM users u WHERE u.gender = 0)
```

Third is similar, just add `AND u.age > 20 AND u.age < 40` to both subqueries.

Fourth;

```
-- Number of associated users above 2
SELECT *, count(p.id) AS user_count FROM profiles p
  JOIN users u ON p.id = u.profile_id
  GROUP BY p.id HAVING count(u.id) > 2
```

Comment: I'll test your queries. They look promising. Do you think the DB design is headed in the right direction, though? Just because it can be queried doesn't mean it is good design.

Comment: The two tables you are showing look ok. Note that my queries aren't optimized for performance. One thing that's unfortunate with your users table, is that you need to filter on a very non unique field with gender. That makes MySQL have to evaluate typically all rows, as an index could be inefficient. But using the bit type will be a lot more efficient than varchar.

Comment: For `gender`, I was thinking of using ENUM (there are 3 genders, 3rd one being transgender). I'm concerned with your statement "you need to filter on a very non unique field with gender" as I don't fully understand what you mean. There is going to definitely be a lot more than just these to query (e.g. a list of "interests" a particular user may have and trying to match such a user to other users with similar interests). Am I headed for a big headache?

Comment: A general rule of thumb for making queries fast, is to filter on fields that will not likely share its value with many rows. For instance if you have 100 000 rows in your users table, and half of these are men, querying on gender=male will have to return half of the rows anyway - so depending on the dbms, it might not use the gender index because it would have to do so many lookups that it's better off doing a full index scan. You shouldn't worry too much about this since unless you're expecting a lot of data. Also for expensive queries, there is always the option of mysql or memcache caches.